# Does a half plane contain intersection of some other half planes?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-analysis

I'm doing research in Optimization and I have found this obstacle in the way.

> If we have set of half planes like $c_ix\leq b_i$ where $i\in \{1,\ldots ,k\}$ there is an algorithm(it would be better if it is polynomial time) such that we can certify $\{\cap _{i\neq p}\{c_ix\leq b_i\}\}\subset \{c_px\leq b_p\}$

If you give me some hint or some references I really appreciate it.

Comment: Besides, this looks like the textbook case of linear programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the maximum of $c_{p}x$ subject to the constraints $c_{i}x\le b_i$ for $i\ne p$. If the maximum is at most $b_p$, the subset relation holds.